# I cannot open file in QT5 for FTP

Tags: c++, qt, ftp

*i want to use qnetworkaccessmanager to use ftp in qt5.14.
first i want to get the details in the directory
so i used command list.
my code is

```
*QUrl url;
    url.setScheme("ftp");
    url.setPort(21);
    url.setUserName(ui->userName->text());
    url.setPassword(ui->password->text());
    url.setHost(ui->FtpAdd->text());
    url.setPath(/hdd/);
    url.setQuery("type=i");
    request.setRawHeader("Command", "LIST");
QNetworkRequest request(url);*
QNetworkReply *reply = networkAM->get(request);
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, [=]() {
        if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
            qDebug() << "Connected to FTP server successfully!";
            QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
            qDebug() << data;
        } else {
            qDebug() << "Failed to connect to FTP server. Error:" << reply->errorString();

        }
        reply->deleteLater();
qDebug()<<url;

    });
```

whatever i do , it output  ** Failed to connect to FTP server. Error: "Cannot open ftp://root:@172.16.20.1:21/hdd/?type=i: is a directory"**
i guarantee that the ftp server is running right
*

i want to know where the problem is?
thanks a lot

Comment: You are called Get(), this will work fine with a single file.  For a Directory Listing I don't think QNetworkManager will do this...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there are a few things wrong in the code you have posted:

```
*QUrl url;
    url.setScheme("ftp");
    url.setPort(21);
    url.setUserName(ui->userName->text());
    url.setPassword(ui->password->text());
    url.setHost(ui->FtpAdd->text());
    url.setPath(/hdd/);
    url.setQuery("type=i");
    request.setRawHeader("Command", "LIST");
QNetworkRequest request(url);*
QNetworkReply *reply = networkAM->get(request);
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, [=]() {
        if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
            qDebug() << "Connected to FTP server successfully!";
            QByteArray data = reply->readAll();
            qDebug() << data;
        } else {
            qDebug() << "Failed to connect to FTP server. Error:" << reply->errorString();

        }
        reply->deleteLater();
qDebug()<<url;

    });
```

1. The setting of the Raw Header should be done AFTER the object has been instantiated, i.e. this:

   request.setRawHeader("Command", "LIST");
   QNetworkRequest request(url);

Should be:

```
QNetworkRequest request(url);
request.setRawHeader("Command", "LIST");
```

2. The Path should be in quotes, so this:

   url.setPath(/hdd/);

Should be:

```
url.setPath("/hdd/");
```

The main problem is that you are called get(), and this method is designed to basically retrieve a single file.  So, when you have the following (I've changed the credentials to a publicly available FTP server for testing):

```
    QUrl url;
        url.setScheme("ftp");
        url.setPort(21);
        url.setUserName("demo");
        url.setPassword("password");
        url.setHost("test.rebex.net");
        url.setPath("/pub/example/");
.
.
.

    QNetworkReply *reply = m_network_manager->get(request);
```

The code is trying to "get" a directory. which it won't do, hence the error.

If you were to change the above to:

```
    QUrl url;
        url.setScheme("ftp");
        url.setPort(21);
        url.setUserName("demo");
        url.setPassword("password");
        url.setHost("test.rebex.net");
        url.setPath("/pub/example/readme.txt");
.
.
.

    QNetworkReply *reply = m_network_manager->get(request);
```

Then it will work and you "get" the file which will then be displayed:

```
Connected to FTP server successfully!
""
QUrl("ftp://demo@test.rebex.net:21/pub/example/readme.txt")
"Welcome,\r\n\r\nYou are connected to an FTP or SFTP server used for testing purposes by Rebex FTP/SSL or Rebex SFTP sample code.\r\nOnly read access is allowed and the FTP download speed is limited to 16KBps.\r\n\r\nFor information about Rebex FTP/SSL, Rebex SFTP and other Rebex .NET components, please visit our website at https://www.rebex.net/\r\n\r\nFor feedback and support, contact support@rebex.net\r\n\r\nThanks!\r\n"
```

So, in answer to your question, "I want to know where the problem is?", the problem is trying to use "Get" for a directory listing.

Comment: yes  i want to use ftp command to get the listing of the diretory.